# Dividir un td en varias partes y que cada una tenga un onclick- HTML

Tags: html, css, tablas

Quiero dividir un `td` en varias partes como sea posible y que cada uno tenga onclick. Por ejemplo
Tengo la siguiente tabla

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que me salga lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver el valor de las celdas de `Age` esta dividida en 2 partes, si es posible tal vez mas, ambas partes deberian tener un evento `onclick`. Busque informacion sobre esto, pero no tengo respuestas, nose si esto sea posible

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], ¿has intentado algo?

Comment: De intentar y probar si, encontre una que se hace con una imagen entre ambos `td`, de investigar mucho, estube casi todo el dia viendo el tema pero como dije ahi no tengo una respuesta correcta @BetaM

Answer (score 2):

Dividimos en tres la última celda, en ella tendremos la línea que divide, el elemento de arriba y el elemento de abajo.

Para la línea debemos de ponerle un borde y rotarla en sentido antihorario mediante `rotate`. Ahora como resulta que el ancho es menor que la diagonal deberemos de asegurarnos que el ancho (`width`) que le pongamos a la línea sea de más del 100%.

Para posicionar los números usamos posicionamiento absoluto y a uno lo pegamos arriba (`top`) y al otro abajo(`bottom`) poniéndole valores bajos. Lo mismo los pegamos a las orillas con los valores bajos a la izquierda(`left`) y a la derecha(`right`) respectivamente.

Finalmente para que se le pueda dar click al número de abajo debemos cambiarle su `z-index` para que se pinte encima de la diagonal.

```js
function arriba1() {
  console.log('arriba1');
}

function arriba2() {
  console.log('arriba2');
}

function arriba3() {
  console.log('arriba3');
}

function abajo1() {
  console.log('abajo1');
}

function abajo2() {
  console.log('abajo2');
}

function abajo3() {
  console.log('abajo3');
}
```

```css
/*Este no es necesario pero lo pone bonito*/

tr td:last-child {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.linea {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  top: 35px;
  bottom: -5px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0px;
  width: 105%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

.diagonal {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}

.diagonal span.arriba {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
}

.diagonal span.abajo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td class="diagonal">
      <span class="arriba" onclick="arriba1()">50</span>
      <span class="abajo" onclick="abajo1()">20</span>
      <div class="linea"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td class="diagonal">
      <span class="arriba" onclick="arriba2()">94</span>
      <span class="abajo" onclick="abajo2()">30</span>
      <div class="linea"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td class="diagonal">
      <span class="arriba" onclick="arriba3()">80</span>
      <span class="abajo" onclick="abajo3()">10</span>
      <div class="linea"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```